# Understanding bits/bytes with hex

Tags: c#

I am unable to figure out how this was found. I am looking to understand how this person is finding this stuff out and how to do it automatically in C# (helps to understand it but also get code). The thread for where this is at is http://forums.radioreference.com/project-25-technologies/228247-p25-control-messages.html and the post is [Post #8](http://forums.radioreference.com/project-25-technologies/228247-p25-control-messages.html#post1663780). Please help me understand bytes and bits. The hex code (I believe to be hex) comes in the format as follows from a police scanner:

```
P25:T0001:80000400FD0008001B5F3A09
```

The quote from the forum is as follows (each two from the above make an octet as its called)

> 80 00 04 00 FD 00 08 00 1B 5F 3A 09
>
> -
>
> Taking the lower 6 bits of the first byte (byte 0) gives you a value of 0, which is a group voice grant
>
> Second byte is the Manufacturer id. Value of 00 is a standard packet
>
> Talkgroup ID is bytes 5 & 6.
>
> Radio ID is bytes 7, 8 & 9
>
> Bytes 10 & 11 are 16 bit CRC.

The code that I currently have gives me the following output which doesn't seem to be correct. The radio ID is 7007 which I don't see how bytes 7, 8, 9 (which are 08 00 1B) gets 7007.

> 128 (0), 0 (0), 4 (4), 0 (0), 253 (61), 0 (0), 8 (8), 0 (0), 27 (27), 95 (31), 58 (58), 9 (9)

and I have no idea what this code even is:

```
String SelectedText = lstboxMessages.SelectedItem.ToString();
String[] SplittedText = SelectedText.Replace("\\r\\n", "").Replace("\r\n", "").Split(new String[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int[] Octets = new int[12];

SplittedText[2] = "80000400FD0008001B5F3A09";

Octets[0] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(0, 2), 16);
Octets[1] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(2, 2), 16);
Octets[2] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(4, 2), 16);
Octets[3] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(6, 2), 16);
Octets[4] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(8, 2), 16);
Octets[5] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(10, 2), 16);
Octets[6] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(12, 2), 16);
Octets[7] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(14, 2), 16);
Octets[8] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(16, 2), 16);
Octets[9] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(18, 2), 16);
Octets[10] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(20, 2), 16);
Octets[11] = Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(22, 2), 16);

String strSpecial = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring(0, 2), 16), 2).PadLeft(8, '0');

String binOpCode = strSpecial.Substring(2, 6);
int OpCode = Convert.ToInt32(binOpCode, 2);

String strReturnMessage = ""; //= SplittedText[2] + " = ";

for (int i = 0; i < Octets.Count(); i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        strReturnMessage += ", ";
    }

    strReturnMessage += Convert.ToString(Octets[i]);
    strReturnMessage += " (" + BinaryToInt(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(SplittedText[2].Substring((i * 2), 2), 16), 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).ToString() + ")";
}

txtLastMessage.Text = strReturnMessage;
```

and BitToInt() is

```
private int BinaryToInt(String strBinary)
{
    String binOpCode = strBinary.Substring(2, 6);
    return Convert.ToInt32(binOpCode, 2);
}
```

Comment: You're miscounting.  The bytes start counting at 0, not 1.  So bytes 7,8,9 are `00 1B 5F`, which in decimal is `7007`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking how to convert hex to decimal by hand:

Okay, take `001B5F`.  Just as in decimal numbers, the leading zeroes can be stripped: `1B5F`.  Now, let's arrange them by the base:

```
   1     B     5   F 
4096   256    16   1
```

Follow so far?  The equivalent in decimal numbers would be 1, 100, 1000, etc. but this is base 16, so each digit goes up by a factor of 16.

Now, your hex digits are:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  A  B  C  D  E  F
```

which in decimal conversion are equivalent:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

So, substitute and multiply:  `1*4096 + 11*256 + 5*16 + 15`, which gives you `7007`.

In code this is a lot easier, since you don't need to do it by hand.  There are many, many ways of doing this, but I'm going to limit myself to once back and forth:

```
int x = 33;
string hex = x.ToString("X2");   // becomes hex 21
```

and then back again:

```
int y = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);    // y is 33
```

Comment: I will also point out for others to know that another way which made more sense to me (but the one lnuyasha gave I'm having a harder time understanding but know its the better way to learn) is at http://www.webelfin.com/webelfindesign/hexdec.html. Because its in a table format, I can't paste it here.

Comment: @GabrielGraves, the math is the same, the link you gave is just more verbose I guess.  The key point you need to get used to is memorizing the hex-to-decimal digit conversions.  Impress your friends at parties.  Also, chicks dig guys who know hex :)